# how to move pin back of view in map?

Tags: android, android-mapview

move the pin to back by clicking other pin and any where in map .please suggest or send me how to do.if any code possible please send me

Answer (score 1):

Set the center of the map when pressing (touch event) on it:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    mapView.getController().setCenter(pin.getPoint());
}
```